# Which Linux flavor was mosted used in 2012

Tags: linux, virtual-machines

I would like to change to Linux OS. 
Mostly i am going to use my desktop for Listening Songs, Watching films and sometimes i will edit audio or video.
Can i install Windows OS as Virtual OS inside the Linux OS?
So can anyone please help me to choose a Linux flavor.

Answer (score 1):

[Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity) says...

[Mint, Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora...](http://www.zdnet.com/the-5-most-popular-linux-distributions-7000003183/)